# Change a Variable Cell using a VBA however I would like to change another cell and this second cell change de first one

Tags: excel, vba

To be more specific, my code is:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   Range("B10").GOALSEEK Goal:=Range("B11").Value, ChangingCell:=Range("B33")
 
End Sub
```

In this case when I set a value in the cell B33, the result in the cell B37 is changed due to keep B10 equal B11 however I would like to know if it is possible to change the value in the cell B37 changing B33 and vice versa keeping B10 equal B11.

Comment: Why VBA? This looks like a perfect thing to be handled by a formula?

Comment: You are correct, but in this case, some cells have formulas which are linked to another cells, so when I try to apply a formula some cells go to 0 or some erros are shown. In other words when a value is set in B33, B10 must be equal to B11 giving me a number in B37 however when I set a value in B37, B10 must be equal to B11 giving me a number in B37. When I try to change the value in B37 to get a different number in B33 the VBA does not allow forcing to keep the previously number.

Comment: Could you share the 'desired' `Excel` formulas in `B33` and `B37`? I know that this cannot be handled with `Excel` formulas. Most probably, you need to use the `Worksheet Change` event with no formulas in `B33` and `B37`.